# How to set Android Home in Ubuntu when the path is in the root folder

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm working in a cordova project, but when i tried to build this project, i got that:

**

> [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try
> setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your
> 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK
> directory.]

**
i installed Android Studio, and by default that program put the SDK in the root folder, so i saw a few answers about this same error and i tried to set this variable as a few people said, but did not work, i tried this:

**

> export HOME="/root"
>
> export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
> PATH="$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools:$PATH"

**
but failed too

i don't find that error, please help, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Paste this code at the end of your ~/.bashrc (/home/**{user}**/.bashrc)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/{user}/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```

Remember to replace **{user}** with your actual username.

Also, Be careful with the correct locations, sometimes it might change according to where you have set the installation directories.